# Condition number on the DFT-like complex vandermonde matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-equations, matrix-rank, condition-number

Given $M \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 < L \le M$, $L \in \mathbb{N}$ consider a set of $L-1$ integers, such that $ 0 \le i_1 < i_2 \ldots < i_{L-1} \le M$

Note that this index set has symmetry inside because they are generated from FFT on a real signal using $M$ equ-spaced sampling. For example, so let's say if $i_1= 1$, then $i_{L-1}$ must be $M-1$.

Then we have the following complex Vandermonde matrix based on the above
$$
\mathbf{A} \triangleq V(e^{2\pi j i_1/M},\ldots,e^{2\pi j i_{L-1}/M}) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & e^{2\pi j i_1/M} & e^{4\pi j i_1/M} & \ldots e^{2(L-1)\pi j i_1/M}\\
1 & e^{2\pi j i_2/M} & e^{4\pi j i_2/M} & \ldots e^{2(L-1)\pi j i_2/M}\\
1 & \ldots &  \ldots & \ldots \\
1 & e^{2\pi j i_{L-1}/M} & e^{4\pi j i_{L-1}/M} & \ldots e^{2(L-1)\pi j i_{L-1}/M}
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{C}^{L\times L}
$$
where $j^2=-1$.

### Observation:

1. If L = M + 1, then $\mathbf{A}$ is the classical DFT matrix, which has perfect conditioning up to scaling a constant. So the problem here can be thought as DFT-like vandermonde matrix.
2. Fixing $i_1,\ldots, i_{L-1}, $I found the $cond(\mathbf{A})$ grows with increasing M, which makes sense because each row would approaching \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1& \ldots & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
   as $M$ increasing.

### Question

I want to know the any useful bound on the condition number of $\mathbf{A}$.